# in Spring Boot, After using environment variables in application.properties How to create Jar package or run on local machine

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a spring boot project which runs on **locally** and works in **docker container** with below specs:

**application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world
spring.datasource.username=nayemapp
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
ADD target/aifarming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  spring-boot-container:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080    # Map port 9090 on the host to port 9090 in the container
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql-container:3306/world
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: nayemapp
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
      SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL-AUTO: update
      SPRING_JPA_SHOW-SQL: "true"
      SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_DIALECT: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
      SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL: "true"
    depends_on:
      - mysql-container      # This ensures that the Spring Boot app starts after the MySQL container
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\nayem\OneDrive\Desktop\docker-volumes:/path/in/container

  mysql-container:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root  # Replace with your desired MySQL root password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: world
      MYSQL_USER: nayemapp
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 3306:3306    # Map port 3307 on the host to port 3306 in the container
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\nayem\OneDrive\Desktop\docker-volumes:/path/in/container
```

But, when I try to use **environment variables** in `application.properties` which is set in `docker-compose.yml`, I can not package it to get the `.jar` file to use in docker. Also, when I try to run it, I get erros like `ClassNotFoundException: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME}`
I set environment variables in application.properties as below:

**application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME}
spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=${SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL-AUTO}
spring.jpa.show-sql=${SPRING_JPA_SHOW-SQL}
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=${SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_DIALECT}
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=${SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL}
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

Comment: if you will change variable name from `${SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME}` to `${SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVERCLASSNAME}` is it will work ?

Comment: Spring can automatically convert environment variables like `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` to properties like `spring.datasource.url`. So I would try removing the properties that you're using environment variables and see if that works.

Comment: Hey @AndreiLisa thanks for replying, but changinig the variable name didn't work.

Comment: just try what @g00glen00b suggested also a good point.

Comment: hey @g00glen00b thanks for replying, but removing the properties from `application.properties` is not working.

Comment: why isn't it working though? Isn't it supposed to work like how I configured it?

Comment: The specified environment variables already override the ones from `application.properties` there is no need to specify them again like this. Environment variables take precedence over the other. You could even remove the whole list of properties from `application.properties` if you are always specifying them as environment or system variables.

Comment: Hello @M.Deinum, thanks for an informative reply. As the environment variables are already in docker-compose.yml file, I removed the properties but when I run it, I'm receiving error description: Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Comment: And you are using your docker-compose.yaml to start the application or is this error  occuring when running the jar? As you still need to specify the parameters for that using either command line parameters or other means (like an application.properties next to the jar file).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen environment variable names with the use of the @ sign in application.properties

Can you try like it?
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=@SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME@

I want to reply as a comment, but I cannot I'm so sorry :(

Comment: hey @BayuSriHernogo thanks. I tried according to your suggestion but didn't work.

Comment: That is for maven to replace the properties upon building **not** for Spring variable substitution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).